# Going from setTimeout AJAX call to Long Polling with timeout

Tags: sql-server-2008, jquery, asp-classic, long-polling

I have created a site which auto refreshes a `DIV` every 15 seconds using a `timeOut`.
This works pretty solid, but it can take up to 5 minutes before the `DIV` is actually updated, which means the script will do the call **20 times** before a change happens. Pretty good waste of costly bandwidth and server performance :)

I have been reading a lot about doing `Long Polling` instead and I've been giving it a go.

My AJAX call was:

```
intval = window.setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'url',
    beforeSend: function() { $('#timerimg').attr('src', 'img/icons/loading.gif'); },
    success: function(data) { $('#ajaxcontent').html(data); },
    complete: function() { $('#timerimg').attr('src', 'img/icons/stop.gif'); }
  });
}, 15000);
```

This function was placed inside the page being refreshed all the time, which made the timeout-function to being kept repeated.

Now I have tried to follow http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery to create a simple Long Polling function

```
(function poll() { 
  $.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'url',
    success: function(data) { $('#ajaxcontent').html(data); },
    complete: poll,
    timeout: 30000
  });
})();
```

If I am setting the url to `hi.txt` and making that write `Hello World!` then it finished constantly and doing a new poll. Which obviously means A LOT of simultaneous polls.

How do I correct this?

**AND:**

The autorefreshing `DIV` is a large chart with calculations from a huge `SQL-Server` query. So maybe it should just check if there has been the slightest change in the `.getRows()` (compared to the original) after the SQL query?

I am doing the whole thing in jQuery and ASP-Classic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long polling is not a client only solution. Long polling requires the server to hold the call until something changes. This means that you will be using up one of your concurrent connections for EVERY client logged in. This can be a problem with some service providers that limit concurrency, so check your ISP policy before you get a 503.

Also you are addressing more than one issue here. The server should keep track of whether or not the last request needs to be updated, or to just send you back the cached response. If you are using long polling, then the server will hold your connection until it has changed.

Previously you were using interval polling. I would suggest continuing that route (with server side caching) instead of dedicating half of your IE bandwidth (2 concurrent max) for an infrequent update. Just have the server kick back a "false" response to your inquiry if things haven't changed.

Comment: It's my own rack-server placed on a very large backbone internet-connection, so I dont believe the concurrent connection-limit are gonna be any problem. The current problem is that the screen wont be instantly updated when the database is.. I've been reading several blogs around the net: When doing the SQL query in the called .asp file, it will first fetch original data from the database and then do a loop all the time fetching the same data again and again and again, until the data has changed, and then send the new data back to the browser... But wont this create a HUGE amount of bandwidth?!

Comment: Regarding the database backend, whenever the data is updated there should be a timestamp, or ask your DBA to provide it. With that timestamp, you can check your last timestamp against it. If it is greater than your last poll, THEN pull the larger query once. Everytime you pull, update your poll with the new time. Also, your long poll shouldn't be hammering the database. Tell it to sleep on it for a second or whatever your use case is for responsiveness.

Comment: So the best thing is to add a "last modified"-timestamp to each row in the database.. and then select the top 1 timestamp descending to withhold with the request's timestamp.. if there is any greater in the current pull, then select all from the database, do the math and push to the user.. that would still be a pull from the DB every 2nd second.. but thats internal trafik which is not a money problem.. so that could be a good solution?

Comment: From the outside looking in I cannot answer that. Running a query on timestamps will be slow without an index, look into setting up an on update trigger to update a single value on a memory table when the data is changed. Looking at that one value in memory is going to be much lighter on your workload then putting one on every single row in a larger table. The only reason you would need a per-item timestamp is if you were pulling out specific rows only.

Comment: Ah, I see.. I will be looking into trigger events then :) Thanks for your help.